# Bigcommerce Stencil Front Matter cannot get global products variable on custom pages

Tags: bigcommerce

I can't seem to get the front matter object Products to populate inside any html file in the /templates/pages/custom/ folders.

/templates/pages/custom/page/about.html

```
---
products:
    featured:
        limit: {{theme_settings.homepage_featured_products_count}}
---
...

{{> components/products/featured products=products.featured columns=theme_settings.homepage_featured_products_column_count theme_settings=../theme_settings}}
```

This same code works in every file in the /templates/pages/ folder, just not in the custom folder.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there no way to use global front matter objects with customLayout files?

Edit: Front Matter objects are only located in the base /templates/pages files, and not in any files in subdirectories.

So, now, is there anyway to send the Front Matter object into my custom page?

Comment: you're not doing anything wrong. This isn't something that has been added to custom templates.

Comment: Is it something that will be? Secondly, how would one go about making custom pages in such a way that they have access to the front matter objects?

I haven't found a way to map something like an about.html to the pages  directory so it can access the front matter objects.